# Windows Time Service is Missing

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, services, time

I have Windows 10 Pro installed on my PC. After the last update I have a problem with the time as it changes continuously either after startup or while using the PC. Searching online, I noticed that Windows Time is missing from the list of my services. I then tried to run the "W32tm /register" command in powershell but things don't change (even after restarting the PC). How can I solve it?

Comment: Check if the other steps described [here](https://windowsreport.com/wrong-time-on-windows-clock-fix/) solve your issue or not.

Comment: Try `Sfc /scannow`, I'd also look into replacing your CMOS battery, or just looking into it in general. Time issues, usually are related to CMOS battery problems

Comment: thank you for the reply but the time changes even when the PC is turned on. Could it still be due to the battery? I checked the time zone and it is correct.